# Game development update for newbie

Tags: java, android, desktop-application, game-engine

I know many topics been here before but I think mine will be the most updated question. I want to start on game development, my target platform is android. I have experienced in web desktop and android application but I have totally no experience in game development. I have read about game development vectors and other stuff which is kind of complicated to me as I am not that good in math. Android and desktop life cycle is very different so is it better for me to start developing games in desktop first and have better understanding.

- How it works or dive into android game development?
- I am not that good in math can I still be a game developer ?

I need high level guidance from game developers about the domain, its challenges and requirements.

Comment: This question fits better here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try libGDX, you can deploy to multiple targets at once.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati and libGDX is? How can be used? Is really the silver bullet that every game developer should learn and use in his/her daily work? Isn't? Why don't you provide an answer? Or maybe is too wide to be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You come very close to getting flagged as a invalid question, but I believe you are seeking guidance, so upvote and a attempt to answer your question.

Consider these when you develop games

- Android bear framework may not be as good as other gaming frameworks for developing games. Mainly since with Android you need to do all the math yourself. Everything from movement to collision detection to correctly timed animation to multiple device support and testing.
- Memory management is a huge issue, which you need to work on big time, if you cant make a game that runs smoothly and that can be fun to play dont release that game.
- It must be fun to play, forget everything else.
- You need a very good graphic designer to help you with backgrounds, characters and emotions. Without which it will be a very crappy looking game, which will be no fun to play.
- You need to engage the user, so you need levels difficulty levels, which is called `gameplay`. So you need a good amount of thought into the story you are using to engage the user.
- Bug fixes as it gets tested in the field is very important. Get a lot of people to play it free. Play it yourself hell a lot before you release.
- Consider learning frameworks like `carona`. Bear Android will be a pain to develop it with the criteria above.

Its a passionate mans job dude, dont do it for fun :). Get in only if you love making games, not only if you love playing them. Get in if you have a excelling gameplay, character and story in mind. Get a good designer to understands color and who can do a artists job too. He will also need to give you images in various sizes, shapes and resolution, so he needs to be around until you release. Since last day you may realize that you need a lower resolution image for the entire set. A team delivers a game, cant be just 1 dude sitting and coding.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote and answer sir. I thought no one will answer my question. Again thanks ^_^

Comment: Keep in mind it will take a few months of focused learning of new frameworks to get in. And dont get too attached to one framework you need to keep learning new ones every 3 months. Else you become stale very very fast. All the best.